# Wildfly domain mode additional validations problems

Tags: java, java-8, migration, wildfly, wildfly-cluster

I am currently working on migrating my company's production environment from JBoss 5 to Wildfly 10 and Java 6 to Java 8, I have heard that the domain operation mode may present some additional validations problems between exchanging messages between DC And HCs, Can anyone with more experience explore this matter and tell if domain mode can be disadvantageous and bring problems in the production environment?

I know that depends on the application and the infrastructure available, I will mention some features used by the application, EJB, JMS, Infinispan to hibernate entity caches, APIs with JAX-RS, I am also creating load balancing based on Metric (heap) with apache to direct the request between servers.

The Environment is composed of several clusters, some larger with about 15 wildfly servers and other smaller ones with 2 servers.

Thanks

Comment: I am reading the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Operating+modes 
but I did not find anything specific related to the question

Answer (score 0):

We just migrated few of our production environments from JBoss 4.2 to WildFly 9 including all third party jar updates + jdk6 to jdk 8.
WildFly comes with almost latest modules of every library, it means you have to also update your code accordingly or you have to exclude those modules in wildfly.

You are referring documentation of WildFly 8. I would recommend if you are planning to upgrade to WildFly 10 then refer https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Operating+modes. There might not be any difference in documentation but its better to refer documentation of same version.

To setup and configure cluster we referred https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/WildFly+9+Cluster+Howto
and
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/High+Availability+Guide

Transactions behavior has also changed in WildFly.

Applications are working fine and it's much easier to maintain in WildFly as compared to JBoss.

There is a tool called [WindUp](http://windup.jboss.org)  which will also provide you an estimate of changes for migration.